# How to vote using REST

Tags: 8

I have an installed [Vote Api](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) in Drupal 8 site.

Also, installed Postman application in my browser.

Just a simple and quick question.

Is there any way to call the Vote Api via REST?

Comment: This appears to be an outstanding issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2730559. So no.